# How to get updated only once when user is in specific region?

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location

Hello everyone I am using `CoreLocation` in my project to get to know if I have reached a certain region. I am not using `startMonitoringForRegion` but instead I am using `startMonitoringForSignificantLocationChange` in the background.

So when I have a location update I check against my stored place and if distance is less or equal my set radius it will send a local notification. Everything works fine except let's say that the user is in the range and he receives the push. Again when he goes in background walk a bit it will certainly show the notification. How to cater for this i.e since I received a notification it wont pop up again and also if when I left that region and re enter will should pop up. I was thinking to use a Boolean value to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may clear notifications in

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
```

And recreate a local notifications excluding the region where you are now

Comment: tks for your reply :) needed the [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications]; teh rest i will handle it with a boolean value :)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is not to use the

```
Boolean notified = FALSE;
```

value as it will loose its value when application get terminated and relaunched.
Why don't you use

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"1" forKey:@"notified"];
```

As this not notify again and again when ever application restarted or relaunched.